# How to click on a child when a palm is rested on a parent

Tags: android

Currently i am unable to click on the buttons when the palm is rested on the screen.Want to able to touch yes/no buttons even though palm rested on screen.Please check below image for more information.[image]

My activity code:: overide onTouch method of yes/no buttons not calling when palm rested and touching buttons

```
    no_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.no_btn);
    yes_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yes_btn);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    bg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    views_parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root1);

    //views_parent.setFocusable(true);
    views_parent.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    bg.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    bg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            return true;
        }

    });
    yes_btn.setId(1);
    no_btn.setId(0);

    no_btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    yes_btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("child onTouch>>>","onTouch>>>2>>"+v.getId());
    if (v.getId() == 0)
    {
        isTouchable = false;
    }else if (v.getId() == 1)
    {
        isTouchable = false;
    }

    return false;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/root"
tools:context="com.example.build.multitouch.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/root1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no_btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="no"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yes_btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="yes"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please share xml file as well.

Comment: can anyone please point to any other resource where we can achieve something similar thanks.

Comment: is this possible ?